# Killing Background processes issue

Tags: android, kill-process

I am using this code to kill all the background processes On the button click, but the problem is sometimes it does not work i.e does not kill any application so is there any other way of doing it? Thnx

```
package com.example.api;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Process;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button theButton;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        theButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        theButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try {

                List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
                PackageManager pm;
                pm = getPackageManager();
                packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(150);
                ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

                for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
                    if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
                    if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("com.example.api")) continue;
                    mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);

                }
                } finally {
               // finish();
                }

            }
        });

    }

}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
```

Comment: check if your application package name is correct "com.example.api"

Answer (score 0):

And you wrote

```
finally {
     finish();
}
```

> That is supposed to finish the activity.